# Is there an algorithm to find the shortest binary representation for every entry within a given range?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, binary, scheme

I have an encoding scheme, but I don't know the name of it. I know there must be an algorithm to encode/decode integers into this binary scheme. The scheme is as follows:

```
   1  2  3   4   5    6    7    8    9     etc.

0  -  0  0   00  00   00   00   000  000
1     1  10  01  01   01   010  001  001
2        11  10  10   100  011  010  010
3            11  110  101  100  011  011
4                111  110  101  100  100
5                     111  110  101  101
6                          111  110  110
7                               111  1110
8                                    1111

etc.
```

Example:
When you have a range of 6 integers (0 to 5) you can use column 6. With this you can save a bit on the numbers 0 and 1. When using column 9, you will save a bit on every number except on 7 and 8.

The 'you will save a bit' is opposed to using 2, 3, 4, or N bit words.

I tried to Google this, but I can't find the right search keywords. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be [Huffman Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) with assumed uniform distribution across all values in any given range.

So for instance, the 5th column is just a huffman encoding for the character set [0-5] (inclusive), which assumes all 6 numbers are of equal probability to occur.

Comment: Hi Dillon Davis, Huffman Encoding crossed my mind. But I think you are right. Using a set of 0-5 with equal frequencies would indeed produce the bits per entry in the column.

Comment: Do you know if there is an algorithm that doesn't require building a tree for every range (0-N) but calculate them directly? There must be a pattern to this. I searched for De Bruijn and some other sequences but couldn't find one that fits this problem. I want to thank you for your suggestion, this gave me an idea. I could preload all the Huffman tables for every 0-N ranges I have.

Comment: @Willempie look into Adaptive Huffman Encoding. As a bonus, it also adapts to the frequency of each digit/character, to become more efficient.